# What does "haven't" refer to?

Tags: grammar

> Edward: How do I know If l can even trust you??
>
> Dr Federicks: You won't. I mean, I hope you're lucky enough to meet
> someone you trust. I regret to say **I haven't**.

What does "haven't" refer to?

Comment: What do you think it refers to? Do you have any guesses? Why are you confused? These are good things to include in your question, both to demonstrate good faith on your part and to provide you a better and more specific answer.

Comment: *I regret to say I haven't **met [been lucky enough to meet]** someone I trust*. Note that in this particular example of "predictably repeated" text being "deleted" from a parallel construction, there's no problem about the embedded pronoun switching from *someone **you** trust* to implicit *someone **I** trust*, because that same switch has already been explicitly performed by ***You're** lucky enough* being "replaced / echoed" by ***I** haven't*.

Comment: Note that in the *exact* context cited here, ***I haven't*** implies negation of ***met***, not ***been lucky enough...*** But in a very similar construction, that might not be the case: *I hope you're lucky enough to be chosen. I regret to say I haven't been* (where ***been*** is syntactically required. Also note that it would be syntactically valid to append ***been*** to the text actually cited - in which case it would mean *I haven't **been so lucky***, rather than *I haven't **met such a person***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means "I haven't met someone whom I can trust." He is trying to express the negative event in his case, what he hopes to happen in case of  Edward.